# User-friendly program to create editable & searchable pdf files, like tax & application forms and such?

Tags: pdf, editing, search, forms

Can somebody recommend user-friendly program that will create ( or convert from Excel & Word, or OpenOffice) editable pdf forms. You know like tax forms, that some of us filled out. Where you can create a form with predefined format and stationary, but let user edit/fill out fields. I need something user-friendly that a regular person can use. I'm NOT looking for a pdf library ( I already use wkhtmltopdf for generating pdfs programmaticaly). The reason is that we have about 400 documents ( internal expense forms, traing forms, etc) in .doc and .xls format that we want to convert to editable pdf ( so that people don't have to fill them out by hand). Coding 400 templates and then converting them using some lib or command line tool - is not my idea of fun, espsecially since those form change all the time. I'd like to just give HR and Quality department the tool, so that they can maintain those documents.

I looked at everything listed on this page ( http://www.cogniview.com/convert-pdf-to-excel/post/pdf-editing-creation-50-open-sourcefree-alternatives-to-adobe-acrobat/ ), but can't find what I need.

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The reason is that we have about 400
>   documents ( internal expense forms,
>   traing forms, etc) in .doc and .xls
>   format that we want to convert to
>   editable pdf ( so that people don't
>   have to fill them out by hand).

You should be able to use OpenOffice.org/unoconv for that.

`unoconv -f pdf test.doc` works for me, producing a fillable test.pdf that works in Evince (this is the same as OOWriter's File->Export->PDF).

You probably want to do some testing to verify that complex table and form layouts are preserved correctly. You may get better results if you were to start with native odf documents.

Comment: Kelly.Thanks for the advice. I can do this: OOWriter's File->Export->PDF, and it works. But what about a "unoconv -f pdf test.doc" I can't find anything about unoconv? Nothing at OpenOffice.org/unoconv - broken page.....

Comment: My mistake, I thought unoconv was part of OO.o, but it is an external program: http://dag.wieers.com/home-made/unoconv/

Debian, at least, packages it, and rpms are available. It is Python and UNO, so I guess it should work on Windows as well